# How to make ASP.NET Core DI crash if wrong ILogger?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I accidentally screwed up the type of Logger I am trying to resolve:

```cs
 public KeyCodeHandler(ILogger logger)
```

This fails to resolve because it needs to be an `ILogger<KeyCodeHandler>`. Easy enough to solve, but I want a test for that

So I wrote this:

```cs
[Fact]
    public void AllDependenciesPresentAndAccountedFor()
    {
        var builder = ProgramHelper.CreateBuilder(Array.Empty<string>());

        var mock = new Mock<IHostEnvironment>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.EnvironmentName).Returns(Environments.Development);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(mock.Object);

        var services = builder.Services;

        var data = new List<string>();
        // Assert
        var exceptions = new List<InvalidOperationException>();
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        foreach (var serviceDescriptor in services)
        {
            var serviceType = serviceDescriptor.ServiceType;

            if (!serviceType.Assembly.GetName().Name!.Contains("InterfaceService"))
            {
                continue;
            }

            data.Add(serviceType.Name);

            try
            {
                provider.GetServices(serviceType);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }

        }

        exceptions.Should().BeEmpty();
    }
```

Confusingly, this test works if run in Rider in Debug mode. It detects the wring `ILogger` and finds the exception. But if I run this test without debug mode it...passes. Also, if I start my service without debug mode, ASP.NET Core happily starts and ignores the error.
I've attempted to set `IsDevelopment` to true, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you add the exception message (and other exception details)?

Comment: There is no exception atm. Thats the Problem. It should be an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand but you said "This fails to resolve". Doesn't this imply an exception?

Comment: It works for me. Please, make sure you don't skip that service in if statement checking for assembly name containing "InterfaceService".

Comment: @Steven What I want to do is to have a failing test here. I want it to find the error mentioned.

Comment: @Prolog Thats not the problem - currently it crashes (correct behaviour) if I start this test in Debug mode. Otherwise it reports no errors.

Comment: What I meant by my comment, is that it fails for both Debug and Release. That's why I still think you're omitting your service when not in Debug mode. What happens if you comment out the if statement? If you cannot do that, try to register an empty test service which uses `lLogger`, then add another condition to the if statement, to make sure that empty test service type never falls into the assembly name check condition.